# How to connect AWS RDS MySQL from Django app from local machine

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

when i try to hook up my Django site to a remote MySQL RDS i get the error:

makemigrations.py:158: RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': (1049, "Unknown database 'mydatabaseinstance'")
warnings.warn(
No changes detected

my config in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabaseinstance',
        'USERNAME': 'xxxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx',
        'HOST': 'xxxxxx.xxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
```

}

I'm confused because I can connect through MySQL Workbench